# DynamoDB - How to have a "Display ID" pattern?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

Let's say I have the following Document:

```
hashKey: "PROJECT:1edb63f3-eb2d-6798-baba-0242ac120005"
name: "My Project"
createdAt: 2023-01-01
```

In my API, the above project would be fetched by its ID, for example

```
GET /api/v1/projects/1edb63f3-eb2d-6798-baba-0242ac120005
```

For the type of Application i'm building, having a shorter, more shareable ID is desired.

Is there a way to do this? Having a user friendly ID that I can somehow also use to GET the object directly

Some ideas that come through my head but I'm unsure:

1. Compressing the ID into a shorter string, then we can use the same algorithm to decompress and get the original one
2. Just create a displayId field of any desired length and type (could even be sequential), and create a lookup table to find the original ID (overkill maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

Just convert to using a shorter and shareable ID as the item’s ID and use that better ID in the partition key for direct lookup.